# Failed to build gem native extension when install gem Cloudinary (Rails 6 & ruby -v 2.6.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Whem I'm trying to run `bundle install`I got this message event if I try to `gem install unf_ext -v '0.0.7.6' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`.

`````
Installing unf_ext 0.0.7.6 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/led8/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.6/ext/unf_ext
/Users/led8/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/ruby -I /Users/led8/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r
./siteconf20200324-15298-1o69dfm.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lstdc++... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/led8/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-static-libstdc++
    --without-static-libstdc++
    --with-stdc++lib
    --without-stdc++lib
/Users/led8/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file.
(RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/led8/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:552:in `try_link0'
    from /Users/led8/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:570:in `try_link'
    from /Users/led8/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:789:in `try_func'
    from /Users/led8/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1016:in `block in have_library'
    from /Users/led8/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:959:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/led8/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/led8/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from /Users/led8/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/led8/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from /Users/led8/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:357:in `postpone'
    from /Users/led8/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:958:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/led8/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1011:in `have_library'
    from extconf.rb:6:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/led8/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.6.0-static/unf_ext-0.0.7.6/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/led8/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.6 for inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/led8/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.6.0-static/unf_ext-0.0.7.6/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing unf_ext (0.0.7.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install unf_ext -v '0.0.7.6' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  cloudinary was resolved to 1.13.2, which depends on
    rest-client was resolved to 2.1.0, which depends on
      http-cookie was resolved to 1.0.3, which depends on
        domain_name was resolved to 0.5.20190701, which depends on
          unf was resolved to 0.1.4, which depends on
            unf_ext````
`````

Comment: Facing the same issue. Can someone help?